# How to show mathematical equations in Android (without using MS Word or images)?

Tags: android, sqlite

Because of the great difficulties with mathematical equations I had a trick I use on Android
(Note that all these equations are only text, not the algebraic properties)

Writing in Word -> Convert to PDF -> then converted into picture

I want to put the images into Mysql server and download them into Android applications.
I do not want users to have access image
  I put them into the database.
The cost of these actions are high, but to my mind, not the other way

If there's one that is easier to please help

Comment: Create an SVG and use one of the variety of SVG rendering libraries available for Android (or `WebView` on newer devices). Or use a `WebView`, MathML, and libraries for that like [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide:-MathJax-in-Android-apps).

Comment: thank you commons ware ,but i want to use text equation like integral and multiple equations

Comment: If Word and a PDF can handle what you want, the alternatives that I identified may also be able to handle what you want.

Comment: In any case, thank you.
  SVg was a new word for me.
You do not have to do a better solution?
I just want the information to be shown to the user without defect.
And that no one can copy it

Comment: People can copy your images in your current approach. If you do not want people copying the data off their device, do not store the data on the device.

Comment: The images are stored in the database as blob
When they were needed. I turned the picture
Do possibility of copying it?

Comment: Sure. They can get the images out of the database. Or, they can take screenshots of the app.

Comment: Please advice ..
What should I do?

Comment: i can forget the screenshot but get data out from database is so bad.Do they not read-only؟

Comment: Please forgive me master.
  I ask a lot of questions